# Images show less crisp than they are

Tags: support

I've asked a number of questions where I included (partial) screenshots, always as a PNG. I noticed that they appear slightly blurred, which is strange, because when you click the image you can see that same image in better quality.

For instance:

[image]

looks OK here, but not on the question's page: [How can I capture keyboard status when my application doesn't have the focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410158).

Can something be done about this?

*FWIW, I'm using Firefox 42 under Windows 7.*

Comment: Are you on a high DPI display (3k/4k/retina)?

Comment: Nope. 1600x1200 NEC MultiSync.

Comment: The blur seems the same to me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JlWVW.png

Comment: @rene What if you click it?

Comment: for me it is still the same: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bfeak.png

Comment: @rene Wait, those look OK to me too, all three of them. The other link I can't judge properly because of the magnification.

Comment: I wasn't sure if they were similar so I magnified the hell out of them to verify.

Answer (score 2):

Images that contain anti-aliased text, like this one, and particularly the kind of text that was rendered with ClearType can only look good when they are rendered at the **exact** same size they had when they were captured.  If they are rescaled then the anti-aliasing effect no longer works well and the text starts to look noticeably fuzzy.  Again especially bad with ClearType, the red and blue fringes now no longer co-incide well with the monitor striping and become visible.

On my machine I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> twice to get the image rendered at its original size and make the text look sharp.  I prefer reading SO content zoomed-in, my eyesight is not what it used to be.  Just running your monitor at a higher DPI setting is enough to get it rescaled automatically.  When you click the image then it is displayed at its captured size and thus looks good.

So feature, not a volkswagen, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to change the page scaling.

Comment: Zooming in or out won't work for me because I'm always working at 100% zoom.

Comment: The image dpi is 96, when you have a 1600x1200 monitor then you probably bumped up to 120 or 144 dpi.

Comment: Then how do you explain that it shows correctly here on meta, but not on the SO main site? It's the same image.

Comment: Your browser remembers the zoom percentage you used on a particular site.  You claim that can't be it, I'm running out of good explanations.  Good luck with it, try to not let it ruin your Christmas :)

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your thoughts anyway. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause of the slight blur. The original image is 90 x 60 pixels, and in my question it's shown resized to 98 x 65 pixels, and scaling up always causes some level of blurring.
The question is why it was scaled up.